# Convert a BindingList<T> to an array of T

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-3.0

What's the easiest way to convert a `BindingList<T>` to a `T[]` ?

EDIT: I'm on 3.0 for this project, so no LINQ.

Comment: Aside: you can still use LINQ with .NET 3.0, as long as you have the C# 3.0 compiler (or VS2008). Just reference LINQBridge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, if you have LINQ (C# 3.0 + either .NET 3.5 or [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx)) you can use `.ToArray()` - otherwise, just create an array and copy the data.

```
T[] arr = new T[list.Count];
list.CopyTo(arr, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

In .Net 2 you have to use `.CopyTo()` method on your `BindingList<T>`

Answer (score 1):

I've changed this post since I noticed you tagged this with .net2.0. You could use a List since it has an ToArray() method.

```
public T[] ToArray<T>(BindingList<T> bindingList) {
    if (bindingList == null)
        return new T[0];

    var list = new List<T>(bindingList);
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

Note: This is indeed a less performant solution than the CopyTo solution that other members have shown. Use their solution instead, this one creates two arrays, the result and one internal to the List instance.

Comment: The question is tagged .net2.0

Comment: @annakata; *strictly* speaking, it is more relevant whether it is C# 2.0 or C# 3.0, as LINQ is still available with .NET 2.0 + C# 3.0 + a few fairly simple methods etc (or just LINQBridge).

Comment: @Tant102 - I preferred your original answer ;-p The List<T> approach is a bit overkill and (for large data, at least) a bit inefficient.